# How to save UI state within a chip while using navigation in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose, android-chips

I have a chip that changes configurations when being clicked on. However, as the user navigates back (popbackstack) or navigates to another screen, the clicked chip re-sets its previous position. As I understood, I will have to use a viewmodel to pass the chips state and in that way save it? I cant find a way though to store the "remembersavable" in a viewmodel.

How can I achieve this? Appreciate any feedback!

My example chip:

```
@Composable
fun CatsChip() {

    val textChipRememberOneState = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    TextChip(
        isSelected = textChipRememberOneState.value,
        shape = Shapes(medium = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)),
        text = "Cats",
        selectedColor = LightGreen,
        onChecked = {
            textChipRememberOneState.value = it
        },
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the state in a `MutableStateFlow` in a `ViewModel`.

To use `ViewModel`s in Compose you need to add the following dependency to your `app/build.gradle` file

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1")
```

Now you can use the `viewModel()` function to get the `ViewModel` instance in your composables.

With `ViewModel`s you do not need to use `rememberSaveable` anymore, since the state will be kept in
the `ViewModel`, however, if you want the state to persist even across process death (not just configuration changes), then you have to save the state in the `SavedStateHandle`.

Here is an example of a `ViewModel` that only keeps the state in memory, but does not save it in the `SavedStateHandle`.

```kotlin
class MemoryOnlyViewModel : ViewModel () {
    val checkedState = MutableStateFlow(false)

    fun onCheckedChange(isChecked: Boolean) = checkedState.update { isChecked }
}
```

Here is an example of a `ViewModel` that saves the state in the `SavedStateHandle`.

```kotlin
class SavedStateViewModel(private val state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    val checkedState = state.getStateFlow(key = CHECKED_STATE_KEY, initialValue = false)

    fun onCheckedChange(isSelected: Boolean) = state.set(key = CHECKED_STATE_KEY, value = isSelected)

    companion object {
        private const val CHECKED_STATE_KEY = "checkedState"
    }
}
```

Then the usage would look like this

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
        
@Composable
fun CatsChip() {
    val vm: SavedStateViewModel = viewModel() // or: val vm = viewModel<SavedStateViewModel>()
    val catsChipState by vm.checkedState.collectAsState()

    TextChip(
        isSelected = catsChipState,
        shape = Shapes(medium = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)),
        text = "Cats",
        selectedColor = LightGreen,
        onChecked = vm::onCheckedChange, // or: onChecked = { vm.onCheckedChange(it) }
    )
}
```

For more use cases see also the [Business Logic section of the Compose State Hoisting documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting#business-logic)

---

Here is a demo `Composable` using Compose navigation and showcasing the two view models from above,
comparing it with `rememberSaveable`, scoping them in two different ways, to the parent context and to
the `NavBackStackEntry`. This shows how different scopes affect the lifecycle of `ViewModel`s.

Requires the Compose navigation dependency in your `app/build.gradle` file

```
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3")
```

You can check the demo by calling `Demo()` in some composable content of your app.
Click the buttons to navigate and see how the backstack changes. The `ViewModel`s and also the `rememberSaveable` that are scoped to the parent context will preserve the state all the time, whereas those that are scoped to each `NavBackStackEntry` will preserve state only for their own navigation destinations, which can be seen when navigating back.
Also the state saved in the `MemoryOnlyViewModel`s will not survive process death, which you can check in the following way:

1. Send the application to the background by pressing the Home button (but do not close it in the app switcher)
2. Kill the process by running the following command in the IDE Terminal tab with the package name of your application

```
adb shell am kill <package_name>
```

3. Open the application again from the app switcher

If you followed the steps correctly and managed to kill and restore the process in this way, then you should notice that only `MemoryOnlyViewModel`s have lost/reset their state.

Here is the whole demo code. Just copy and paste to a new Kotlin file and call the Demo() composable from a composable content.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.AddCircle
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Clear
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update

class MemoryOnlyViewModel : ViewModel () {
    val checkedState = MutableStateFlow(false)

    fun onCheckedChange(isChecked: Boolean) = checkedState.update { isChecked }
}

class SavedStateViewModel(private val state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    val checkedState = state.getStateFlow(key = CHECKED_STATE_KEY, initialValue = false)

    fun onCheckedChange(isSelected: Boolean) = state.set(key = CHECKED_STATE_KEY, value = isSelected)

    companion object {
        private const val CHECKED_STATE_KEY = "checkedState"
    }
}
    
@Composable
fun Demo() {    
    @Composable
    fun SimpleChip(
        text: String,
        isSelected: Boolean,
        onChecked: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    ) {
        Surface(
            onClick = { onChecked(!isSelected) },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            color = if (isSelected) Color(0xFF7986CB) else Color.LightGray,
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            ) {
                Text(text)
                Icon(
                    imageVector = if (isSelected) Icons.Default.Clear else Icons.Default.AddCircle,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            }
        }
    }

    // These VMs are scoped to the lifecycle of the parent context (likely a ComponentActivity)
    val parentMemoryOnlyVm: MemoryOnlyViewModel = viewModel()
    val parentSavedStateVm: SavedStateViewModel = viewModel()
    var parentSaveable by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    @Composable
    @Suppress("UnusedReceiverParameter")
    fun ColumnScope.DemoScreen(text: String) {
        Text(text)

        val parentMemoryOnlyState by parentMemoryOnlyVm.checkedState.collectAsState()

        SimpleChip(text = "MemoryOnly VM (parent scoped)",
            isSelected = parentMemoryOnlyState, onChecked = parentMemoryOnlyVm::onCheckedChange)

        val navMemoryOnlyVm: MemoryOnlyViewModel = viewModel()
        val navMemoryOnlyState by navMemoryOnlyVm.checkedState.collectAsState()

        SimpleChip(text = "MemoryOnly VM (nav scoped)",
            isSelected = navMemoryOnlyState, onChecked = navMemoryOnlyVm::onCheckedChange)


        val parentSavedState by parentSavedStateVm.checkedState.collectAsState()

        SimpleChip(text = "SavedState VM (parent scoped)",
            isSelected = parentSavedState, onChecked = parentSavedStateVm::onCheckedChange)

        val navSavedStateVm: SavedStateViewModel = viewModel()
        val navSavedState by navSavedStateVm.checkedState.collectAsState()

        SimpleChip(text = "SavedState VM (nav scoped)",
            isSelected = navSavedState, onChecked = navSavedStateVm::onCheckedChange)


        SimpleChip(text = "rememberSaveable (parent scoped)",
            isSelected = parentSaveable, onChecked = { parentSaveable = it })

        var navSaveable by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

        SimpleChip(text = "rememberSaveable (nav scoped)",
            isSelected = navSaveable, onChecked = { navSaveable = it })
    }

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    @Composable
    fun BackButton() = Button(onClick = { navController.navigateUp() }) {
        Text("Go back")
    }

    @Composable
    fun NavButton(route: String) = Button(onClick = { navController.navigate(route) }) {
        Text("Navigate to $route")
    }

    Column {
        val currentEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val backStack = remember(currentEntry) {
            navController.backQueue
                .mapNotNull { it.destination.route }
                .joinToString(" > ")
        }
        Text(text = "Backstack: $backStack")

        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "start") {
            composable("start") {
                Row { NavButton(route = "A"); NavButton(route = "B") }
            }
            composable("A") {
                Column {
                    Row { BackButton(); NavButton(route = "B") }
                    DemoScreen("Screen A")
                }
            }
            composable("B") {
                Column {
                    Row { BackButton(); NavButton(route = "A") }
                    DemoScreen("Screen B")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late respons! I tried the code you suggested but I get an error in MemoryOnlyViewModel regarding this segment:         val backStack = remember(currentEntry) {
            navController.backQueue
                .mapNotNull { it.destination.route }
                .joinToString(" > ")
        }

Comment: Error reads: "Cannot access 'backQueue': it is invisible (private in a supertype) in 'NavHostController'" @Ma3x

Comment: @JosefM The demo is using `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3`, have you added it to the dependencies as described above? The demo itself is not needed for you to implement the solution in your case. See the first part of the answer for that.

Comment: sorry again for the slight delay to answer, have more time now to try to solve it. Yes I have added it but the error still persist. Is it cause I am targeting android 33 or ? @Ma3x

Comment: I created a video so you can see it as well. Note that I copied the exact code as you wrote as a demo: https://gyazo.com/0903405e964c6ad452317d84e2519c70

Comment: @JosefM Which compose version are you using? Just for the demo, you can comment out `val backstack` and `Text(text = "Backstack: $backStack")` since those are just to display the current state of the back stack. The demo will still work even without that extra info displayed.

Comment: This actually solved my problem and is very well explained as well! Thank you for the time and energy you put in, wish you nothing but the best homie! @Ma3x

Comment: Actually I re-read your comment and you are right. One preserve's it within the navigation and configuration changes while the other preserves it for the entire duration, regardless of navigation!